# PHP Curl Force Content-Type

Tags: php, ajax, curl, http-headers, content-type

Even though I set the content type to text/plain, CURLOP_POSTFIELDS appears to be overwriting it to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username etc..');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "type" => "POST",
    "Accept" => "*/*",
    "Content-Type:" => "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "X-AjaxPro-Method" => "Authenticate2",
    "Accept-Language" => "en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection" => "keep-alive",
```

Comment: You CANNOT use associative arrays in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, you must add array items like this: array('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'Connection: keep-alive', ... )

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to remove the colon after Content-Type. Otherwise, try this:

```
$headers = array(
    'type: POST',
    'Accept: */*',
    'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'X-AjaxPro-Method: Authenticate2',
    'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```